# Django Ajax login form

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, jquery

I am trying to submit a login form using ajax. I am confused as to how I am supposed to handle the exceptions/successful responses. I am getting a 200 OK from the server and the form returns error's either by the password/username field. How can I get a error message for to display or redirect the user to the appropriate page depending on the server response?

**JQUERY:**

```
56 $(window).load(function(){                                                                                                                  
57 $('#login_form').submit(function(e){                                                                                                        
58             e.preventDefault();                                                                                                             
59     var request_url = document.getElementById('next').value                                                                             
60          $.ajax({                                                                                                                           
61             type:"POST",                                                                                                                    
62             url: $(this).attr('action'),                                                                                                    
63             data: $('#login_form').serialize(),                                                                                             
64             success: function(response){ $('#msg').text(response);                                                                          
65             console.log(response);                                                                                                          
66             },                                                                                                                              
67             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert( $('#login_error').text('Username already taken. Please select another one.')}, 
68           });                                                                                                                               
69     });                                                                                                                                     
70 });
```

**VIEW: UPDATED**

```
51 def login(request):                                                                                                                         
52     if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                            
53         request.session.set_test_cookie()                                                                                                   
54         login_form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)                                                                              
55         if login_form.is_valid():                                                                                                           
56             if request.is_ajax:                                                                                                             
57                 user = django_login(request, login_form.get_user())                                                                         
58                 if user is not None:                                                                                                        
59                     return HttpResponseRedirect(request.REQUEST.get('next', '/'))
           **else:**                                                                                                                               
61                **return HttpResponseForbidden() # catch invalid ajax and all non ajax**                                        
60     else:                                                                                                                                   
61         login_form = AuthenticationForm(request)                                                                                            
62                                                                                                                                             
63     c = Context({                                                                                                                           
64         'next': request.REQUEST.get('next'),                                                                                                
65         'login_form': login_form,                                                                                                           
66         'request':request,                                                                                                                  
67     })                                                                                                                                      
68     return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**FORM:**

```
7   <tt id="login_error"></tt>                                                                                                                            
8   <form id="login_form" action="" method="post">                                                                                            
9                                                                                                                                             
10     {{ login_form }}                                                                                                                        
11     <input type="submit" value="login"/>                                                                                                    
12     <input type="hidden" id="request_path" name="next" value="/"/>                                                                          
13   </form>                                                                                                                                   
14 <p>{{ request.get_full_path }}</p>                                                                                                          
15 <tt id='msg'></tt>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it's certainly better practice to do this with a json, you can get away without, assuming you're not really passing much info back from the server. On the django side swap out the `HttpResponseRedirect` for an `HttpResponse` using the redirect URL as your message. Also add an `HttpResponseForbidden` for the case that ajax login fails.

```
def login(request):                                                                                                                         
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                            
        request.session.set_test_cookie()                                                                                                   
        login_form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)                                                                              
        if login_form.is_valid():                                                                                                           
            if request.is_ajax:                                                                                                             
                user = django_login(request, login_form.get_user())                                                                         
                if user is not None:                                                                                                        
                    return HttpResponse(request.REQUEST.get('next', '/'))   
        return HttpResponseForbidden() # catch invalid ajax and all non ajax                                                        
    else:                                                                                                                                   
        login_form = AuthenticationForm()                                                                                                                                        
    c = Context({                                                                                                                           
        'next': request.REQUEST.get('next'),                                                                                                
        'login_form': login_form,                                                                                                                         
        'request':request,                                                                                                                  
    })                                                                                                                                      
    return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then on the javascript side, check the status code of the response. If it's 200, then that's your `HttpResponse` - you want to redirect to the url in the response message. If it's a 403, then that's your HttpResponseForbidden - login has failed. You can get away with a standard 'login failed' error message.

```
$.ajax({                                                                                                                           
    type:"POST",                                                                                                                    
    url: $(this).attr('action'),                                                                                                    
    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),  
    // the success function is called in the case of an http 200 response                                                                                  
    success: function(response){ 
        // redirect to the required url
        window.location = response;                                                                                                     
     },                                                                                                                              
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('login failed - please try again'); 
    }, 
});
```

I'm afraid I haven't tested this, but it should give you an idea.

For more info look at the [docs for django's HttpResponse objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/). Then check out the [jquery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It's worth noting you'll need to make sure you're handling the csrf token properly or you'll hit problems with ajax forms - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Thanks Aidan! It worked. Now the only thing I need to figure out is how to parse out the 'next' value from the response so I can redirect the page properly. :)

Comment: It shouldn't need parsing, I'd expect it to be a string (I don't know without seeing how it was set though). My guess is that there isn't an attribute 'next' in the POST or GET data so the default value '/' is being used. You'll need to find out how it's being set. Check out the docs here for more info on the request.REQUEST dictionary - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST

Comment: There is a next attribute: Form Dataview URL encoded "username:tester,
password:admin, next:/" the next value correlates to <input type="hidden" id="request_path" name="next" value="/"/>. So it's returning the value correctly in the response, I am just not sure why its not redirecting the user to '/'. If I hardcode the window.location = '/' the user is redirected, but the user could be on a different page, so I would like them to be redirected to the appropriate page.

Comment: how about window.location.replace(response);?

Comment: YO! I figured it your. It was a pretty easy work around. I just defined a new variable: var "request_url = document.getElementById('next').value". Then I added "window.location = request_url;" and when there is a successful login Users are redirected properly. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.REQUEST.get('next', '/'))
```

You obviously cant use that if you are doing ajax , the client must be responsible of the redirection/display/whatever is sent back in the Ajax response. If the login is successful , send a JSON response telling the client to redirect itself( with javascript redirection ) , if it is not , send a JSON response with the list of errors and display them using javascript.

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect is an http response with a status code 301. The status code is very easily accessible to a javascript XMLHttpRequest object (or jQuery ajax function). It might not be best practice (I don't know), But it's nonsense to say you 'obviously can't' use the http header to pass this info to the client.

Comment: OK, my bad, I've done a bit of further reading, and it looks like the 300 codes aren't accessible like the other http status codes are (as the XMLHttpRequest redirects before returning and gives the status code associated with the redirect url). I still don't think it's right to say you 'obviously can't' use HttpResponseRedirect. (@camus if you want to make a minor change to your answer I'll remove my negative vote - I'm not allow to do it unless the answer changes)